# Changing way of declaring variables in c++

Tags: c++, variables

Is it possible to change the way of declaring variables and for it to accept any type of variable with c++ so something like this:

```
int main()
{
declare x = "Hello World!"
declare y = 1.2
}
```

Comment: `#define variable 5`

Comment: `auto x = "Hello World!";` is legal; however what type is `x` and what can you do with it ?  If you don't know the type of a variable it can hard to know how you can manipulate it.

Comment: If you follow a [decent book](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/817643) from the last decade, it should cover it. What does your book say?

Comment: The answer is yes you can do this with `auto` but its not a good idea to abuse this as it makes code less readable. People who have to read your code (including yourself in 6 months) will be unhappy with your decision to do this.

Answer (score 4):

With C++11 and newer, you can use `auto`. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto for more info.

With C++17 and newer, you can use `std::any`. This is more useful if you are loading a std::vector with arbitrary data.

However, in my experience as a software engineer, too much auto/any usage can lead to unclear code.

Comment: auto works great, is there any way to rename it so instead of auto it says define or something like that?

Comment: @JoakimHjalmarsson Why would you want to do that?

Comment: @JoakimHjalmarsson, I dont believe you can. ```auto``` is a keyword that directs the compiler to deduce the type. Because its not actually a type itself, you can't use ```using```. Trying to do something like ```#define auto define;``` probably wont work for the same reason. Also... why not just use auto? Or better yet, define your type?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the `auto` keyword